# CodeSandbox doesn't display anything in the preview

Tags: html, codesandbox

As the image shows, I created a default static template project in CodeSandbox, and the preview doesn't update at all. I looked up everywhere and can't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Can you save the file? It looks like the index.html file hasn't been saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I need to save the file every time in order for the changes to display. Or I can go to File/Preferences/Setting to configure the autosave settings